# Deep link to my app from chat apps

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, viber

I have an Android app that can be launched using a deep link. 
The deep link is in the form: http://www.my_app_url.com/pathPrefix.

When I post this link as message in a Viber or Facebook conversation, it redirects to a webview of my app on the Playstore instead of launching my app.

Note: On Facebook, it shows a preview of my app, if I click on the preview, it launches my app correctly.

This works as expected on WhatsApp.

Can someone assist?

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a fix?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent facebook open links in its browser, in facebook `App Settings` toggle on `Links open externally`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't seem to work on Messenger. And I can't ask users to toggle a button, it would be a hassle.